# Проверка числа на n-значность числа

Tags: c++

Программа запрашивает у пользователя шестизначное число. Вывести на экран, соблюдал ли он правила. Т.е., ввель ли user шестизначное число.

Чтобы проверить, шестизначное ли число, я делил это число на `1000000`, так как в данном случае шестизначное число должно давать 0.
Проверка работает правильно с числами типа: `1234567`, `12`, `789625244242` и т.п. (программа оповещает, что число введено не шестизначное)

Работает не правильно с астрономическими числами : `2e10`, `2e8` ...
(программа выводит, что числа шестизначные).
Поэтому мне кажется, что мой алгоритм не правильный.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно решить эту задачу. Спасибо.

Comment: а если не делить,а вычитать 999 999 или складывать?

Comment: Форматировать в строку и проверить регэкспом на строго 6 цифр (или не более 6 цифр - я так и не понял). *я делил это число на 1000000, так как в данном случае шестизначное число должно давать 0. Проверка работает правильно с числами типа: 1234567, 12, 789625244242 и т.п.* Для `12 ` должно было сработать неправильно.

Comment: `99999 < x < 1000000`

Comment: `10^(n-1) - 1 < x < 10^n`

Comment: @slippyk Юзер - существо творческое... с него станется ввести что-то не очень целое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string s;
cin >> s;
if (s[0] != '0' && std::all_of(s.begin(), s.end(),
                [](const char& c) { return isdigit(c); }) && s.size() == 6)
    cout << "ok";
```

так хотели?

Comment: Считается ли `000001` "шестизначным числом"?

Comment: @AnT,  если скажу считается, всеравно не поверите :))